# Sub for Simpson's 1/3 in Excel VBA, But an error appears ("Object required")

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code for a sub to Simpson 1/3 rule. I have the code for the function, but it doesn't work with the small adjustments I've been required to do in the Sub. The Sub must use `SimpsonResultCell.Value` to either display:

- A message (when the number of points isn’t odd) or
- TheresultfromtheSimpson1/3equation.

The message to be used is: " An even number of intervals is necessary (odd number of points)".

So here is the code I have:

```vb
Sub Simpson13Sub()
    Dim xData As Range, yData As Range
    Dim x() As Double, y() As Double, h As Double, sum As Double
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer, np As Integer, SimpsonResultCell As Integer

    Set xData = Application.InputBox("Select cell with x Data", Type:=8)
    Set yData = Application.InputBox("Select cell with y Data", Type:=8)
    Set SimpsonResultCell = Application.InputBox("Select cell to display result", Type:=8) ' object required appears here
    np = xData.Count 'number of points
    n = np - 1 'number of intervals

    If (n Mod 2 <> 0) Then
        SimpsonResultCell = "An even number of intervals is necessary (odd number of points)"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Do
            ReDim x(0 To n)
            ReDim y(0 To n)
            For i = 0 To n
                x(i) = xData(i + 1)
                y(i) = yData(i + 1)
            Next i
                sum = y(0) + y(n)
            For i = 1 To n - 1 Step 2
            sum = sum + 4 * y(i)
            Next i
            For i = 2 To n - 2 Step 2
                sum = sum + 2 * y(i)
            Next i
                h = (x(n) - x(0)) / n
                SimpsonResultCell = h * sum / 3
        Exit Do
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is coming from this declaration:

```
SimpsonResultCell As Integer
```

And this assignment:

```
Set SimpsonResultCell = Application.InputBox("Select cell to display result", Type:=8)
```

The syntax `Set Foo = Application.InputBox` returns a Range object.  You are trying to assign it to an Integer. All you should need to do is use the proper Dim statement:

```
Dim SimpsonResultCell As Range
```